# Exposing Inline function vs declared function in service AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble understanding why the follow code doesn't work.

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/books/BooksController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/dataService.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="BooksController as vm">
        <h3>All Books</h3>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="book in vm.allBooks">
                    {{ book.title }} - {{ book.author }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

`BookController.js`

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  var BooksController = function(dataService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.allBooks = dataService.getAllBooks;

  }

  app.controller('BooksController', ["dataService", BooksController]);
})();
```

`dataService.js`

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('app');

  var dataService = function() {

    return {
      getAllBooks: getAllBooks
    };

    var getAllBooks = function() {
      return [{
          book_id: 1,
          title: "Harry Pptter and the Deathly Hallows",
          author: "J.K. Rowling",
          year_published: 2000
        },
        {
          book_id: 2,
          title: "The Cat in the Hat",
          author: "Dr. Seuss",
          year_published: 1957
        },
        {
          book_id: 3,
          title: "Encyclopedia Brown, Boy Detective",
          author: "Donald J. Sobol",
          year_published: 1963
        }
      ];
    };
  }

  app.factory('dataService', dataService);
})();
```

The problem seems to be when I expose the methods through the service using:

```
return {
    getAllBooks: getAllBooks
};
```

If I change the declaration of the function `getAllBooks` to look like this,

```
function getAllBooks() {
    ...
}
```

and call the service in my controller as:

```
vm.allBooks = dataService.getAllBooks()
```

It'll work fine.

My question is, why doesn't it work for declare functions and putting them in variables? Is it because the function is only defined, but not actually executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because function expression is not hoisted, and function declaration is hoisted.

You just need to put return statement after the function expression.

So put this return statement after the function expression

```
return {
    getAllBooks: getAllBooks
};
```

## Explanation

In javascript functions can be hoisted, which means you can use them before declaring them.

But this is limited to function declarations only, not function expressions.

**Function declaration example:**

```
testFunction();//this will print this function is hoisted
function testFunction(){
 console.log("this function is hoisted");
}
```

**Function expression example:**

```
testFunction(); //Error because testFunction expression is not hoisted
var testFunction = function(){
 //this functions is not hoisted
}
```

For more information about hoisting these two links are really helpful
https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around the hoisting issue is to write your factory this way. Create an object within the factory then attach each method to it and then just return the object and your method(s) will be available in your controller.

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('app');

var dataService = function() {

var factory = {};

factory.getAllBooks = function() {
  return [];
};

return factory;
}

app.factory('dataService', dataService);
})();
```